# (Resolved) How to export annotations in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, annotation

Is there a way to access annotations, save or export them as csv or xls?

Where they are stored? I can´t find that data anywhere.

Comment: which kind of annotations?

Comment: Text annotations are stored in the qgis file itself. You can open this file in a text editing program such as Notepad.

Comment: What are you trying to do with them?

Comment: I am initiating modifications after the client has seen the work and I predict that it will be necessary to take many notes to check later. In the end I have to see if it is useful to have a list with the separate notes, and if it is necessary to print the notes.

I already duplicated the qgs file and saw that I can do some cleaning in Notepad ++ with the XML Tools plugin.